# MYSQL insert or update if exists on a one-way composite primary key table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-update

I've got a **friendship** table between users that looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE user_relations (
pkUser1 INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
pkUser2 INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
pkRelationsType TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(pkUser1,pkUser2),
FOREIGN KEY(pkuser1) references users(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(pkuser2) references users(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(pkRelationsType) references user_relations_type(ID)
);
```

`pkRelationsType` is a pointer to another table that defines the kind of relation the users have (friendship(1),pending(2) or blocked(3))

If **user 1** is friend with **user 2** I've got only one instance `|1|2|1|` and **NOT also** `|2|1|1|`.

The thing is, in order to block a user I have to keep in mind the relation can be already made (users can be already friends or even have the pending friendship petition) so I am trying to insert the data or update it if the relation does not exist already.

I have this for the **friendship request send**, but this just ignores the the insert if the data exists already.

```
INSERT INTO
user_relations(pkUser1,pkUser2,pkRelationsType)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT :sender0,:target0,2) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT pkUser1 FROM user_relations
    WHERE 
    (pkUser1= :sender1 AND pkUser2=:target1) OR (pkUser1=:sender2 AND pkUser1=:target2) LIMIT 1)
```

Due to the nature of the table I cannot use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

I've been thinking about handling it with PHP, searching for the relation and it's order if exists and then doing one thing or another but it seems like a waste of processing.

Please note that I'm not a MYSQL expert even though I've handled myself so far.
Hope I have explained myself well enough.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If you can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, then you need to decide if you can use an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`, if you want more than one operation done server side that will probably require a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you are only keeping the "latest" relationship.  If this is the case, why don't you DELETE the relationship first, then INSERT the new one?

Comment: I was somehow too stubborn to realize I could have just done that, thank you.